# Installing a package on Mac

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to instll sigproextractor package on my Mac

I tried

```
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

But whatever I am trying says that can't find pip

Any help?

Comment: If you which which pip what  happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you could try `python3 -m pip install package`

Comment: Sorry I am trying to install wget but says checking for GLIB... no
configure: error: Either a previously installed pkg-config or "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" could not be found. Please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values or pass --with-internal-glib to configure to use the bundled copy.
pc-133-235:pkg-config-0.29 fi1d18$ if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
-bash: !requireNamespace: event not found

Answer (score 2):

At a guess you don't have python3 installed and hence pip3

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x

Personally I would install via Anaconda3 and skip a direct Python3 installation altogether. The answer above recommends using homebrew, again personally I wouldn't touch it and go straight for a full Anaconda3 installation. You might be able to install via

```
conda install -c XXX sigproextractor
```

Where XXX is the channel, but its certainly on github. Anaconda3 is very easy to install.